# Extract a substring in a string

Tags: python

I have a list of strings with the same pattern and I want to extract the middle of those strings

```py
my_list=["This is my first string","This is my second string"]
my_list2=[string[5:] for string in my_list]
my_list2=[string[:-7] for string in my_list]
```

Output: `["is my first","is my second"]`
My solution is working but How can I simplify the two list comprehensions into one line of code ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever you use a list comprehension, it generates a new list, therefore, your last saved value in `my_list2` was overwritten. There is no reason to use 2 list comprehensions then:

```py
In [1]: my_list=["This is my first string","This is my second string"]
In [2]: [string[5:-7] for string in my_list]
Out[2]: ['is my first', 'is my second']
```

Answer (score -1):

As far I understand your problem you are just removing first and last word
So, for this use split and exclude first and last words